# How do I show all combinations?

Tags: php, math

I searched, can't find anything: How do I do this?

I enter $x = 'tlagre';

I want it to return every single letter combination, down to four.

i.e. - "tlagr" "gratl" "lat" "rat"

I've found some that can do this but none will do every number of letters (they all just do the exact same # of letters as given in $x

Comment: Words that are larger (8+ letters) will be difficult to do in PHP on a regular webserver

Comment: means you want only four words with unique character from any given given word....??????

Answer (score 4):

The search term you should probably be looking at is something like `php string permutations` instead of `combinations`. A permutation is an arrangement of items where the order of each item matters (so `late` and `teal` are different strings), while a combination is an arrangement where the order doesn't matter (`late` and `teal` are considered identical because they use the same letters).

Here's a few links from Google:

- [**String permutation in PHP « Christer's blog o' fun**](http://cogo.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/string-permutation-in-php/)
- [**String Permutation Class - PHP Classes**](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/200.html)

Given an algorithm `P` that generates all the permutations of a string, an algorithm `C` that generates all the combinations of length `N` of some string, and a string `S` of length `M`, here's another algorithm that will generate all the permutations of `S` of length `1...M`:

```
s = "..."
results = []
for (i = 1; i < s.length; ++i) {
  // All combinations of S of length i.
  combinations = C(s, i)

  // All permutations of S of length i.
  results.append(P(combinations))
}

// All permutations of S of length 1..[s.length].
return results
```